# Как продолжить установку Astra Linux?

Tags: linux, astra-linux

Записал на флешку образ iso Astra Linux (orel-1.11-14.04.2016_17.10_livecd). И не могу понять как дальше продолжить установку. Застрял на boot menu , предлагает выбрать либо русскую либо английскую версию, выбираю - обновляется меню и появляется секундомер. В низу есть описание: `"Press Enter to boot a Tab to edit a menu entry."`

Comment: И что происходит, если нажать <Enter>?

Comment: avp - обновляется меню и появляется секундомер, с тем же меню, выбора языков

Comment: скорее всего неверно сделана флешка. И скорее всего флешка сделана для bios загрузки, а комп использует uefi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Всё дело в выборе программа записи.
К сожалению UltraISO при записи не видит скрытые файлы в образе.
LiveCD надо записывать с помощью утилиты dd из Linux или Rufus из Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Вот тут примерно  описан порядок создания установочного образа с использованием штатной утилиты.

https://entnet.ru/client/soft/plus/66-sistemnye-programmy/sozdanie-zagruzochnogo-diska-ili-flesh-nakopitelya.html

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! [Ссылки на внешние ресурсы — это прекрасно, но оставьте вместе со ссылкой описание, чтобы другие пользователи имели представление о её содержимом. Всегда цитируйте самую необходимую информацию, которую вы взяли из указанного источника, на случай если он недоступен или навсегда закрыт.](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). дополнить ответ можно, нажав [edit]